# Promise inside a settimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, delay, settimeout

I'm trying to run promises in a 1 second delay from each other, as the API server I'm working with has a 1 request per second limit.

Here is my code currently

```
var delay = 0;
return categories.reduce(function(promise, category) {
  var id = setTimeout(function() {
    promise.then(function() {

      return client.itemSearch({
        searchIndex: configuration.SearchIndex,
        CategoryID: category.id,
        Keywords: currentKeyword

      }).then(function(results) {
        var title = results[0].Title;
        var cat = category.name;
        var price = results[0].Price;

        return db.insertProduct(title, cat, price);
      });
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("error", err);
    });

  }, delay * 1000);

  delay += 1;
}, Promise.resolve());
```

For every time it loops over, it increases the delay by one, so that the next item will start with a delay of 1 extra second.

So if its the first item, its 0*1 = 0, then 1*1 = 1, then 2*1 = 2... so on

For some reason, it doesnt work, without the settimeout it works perfectly.

As far as I can tell, there shouldnt be a problem with starting a promise after a delay, unless maybe it has something to do with the variables not having a right value after when the delay is finished. If that's the case, how can i fix that, maybe pass on the variables?

I appreciate every help I can get.

Comment: @Quentin youre gonna have to be more specific, which function, the `itemsearch()`, or the `promise.then()`?

Comment: @Quentin youre gonna have to excuse me, im still a bit new to javascript and nodejs. Im not running settimeout once, i run it for every item in the categories array, see `categories.reduce()`. And the return statement is because inside the settimeout im trying to run promises, the return statements are for them.

Comment: @Quentin correct me if im wrong, but `setTimeout` accepts the first variable as a function, and the second as the delay. Im not sure im getting what you mean by the only function i pass onto `setTimeout`

Comment: Something like [this](http://ideone.com/jcB28w), should work

Comment: @thefourtheye i copied your example word to word, it didnt work. Im curious, why is the resolve ran at the end of the delay, and not when the promised is finished?

Comment: @Quentin youre right, it shouldnt have a return statement, ill remove it

Comment: I am sorry, it should have been `resolve(db.insertProduct(...results));`, the `result` is not necessary.

Comment: @thefourtheye wait, `resolve(db.insert....)` at the same line as in the code you provided earlier? if thats the case what do i do with the insert im doing from the `then()` function inside?

Comment: Sorry, I am very sleepy now. Please ignore my comments if they didn't help. I am really sorry for all the inconveniences. I'll take a look at this in the morning.

Comment: @thefourtheye i switched the `return db.insert...` statement with `resolve(db.insert...)` and it worked **perfectly!**

If you want, post it as a solution and ill mark it

Answer (score 1):

Using [`async.eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#each), you can process each of these in series and execute the asynchronous callback 1 second after each request finishes:

```
async.eachSeries(categories, function(category, callback) {
  client.itemSearch({
    searchIndex: configuration.SearchIndex,
    CategoryID: category.id,
    Keywords: currentKeyword
  }).then(function(results) {
    // we don't need to wait after the database here, just after the request
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);

    var title = results[0].Title;
    var cat = category.name;
    var price = results[0].Price;

    db.insertProduct(title, cat, price);
  }).catch(callback);
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('error', err);
  }
});
```